# How to enable MySQL's query log (see all SQL queries as they come)

Tags: mysql

When developing an application that uses MySQL, it can be useful to watch in real time what requests are being made.

How to see all incoming MySQL queries?

Answer (score 16):

As root, edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and add this paragraph at the bottom:

```
[mysqld]
general_log=on
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/query.log
```

Still as root, run these commands:

```
service mysql stop
service mysql start
```

Then observe the log:

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/query.log
```

Please beware that this setting makes MySQL about 15% slower, so remove or comment the paragraph (then restart) when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: `service mysql stop` asking password, I have solution without password. try : `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` then `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` . This will bypass password prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Although Nicolas Raoul's answer is right on point, note that as of mysql-server-5.7, the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file is constructed from the config files in both `/etc/mysql/conf.d` and `/etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d`.

So for the solution to work, the file: `/etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` has to be modified.  So, the lines:

```
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
```

Have to be uncommented, the file saved, and the service restarted with `sudo service mysql restart`.

Otherwise, you might get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command using linux shell script

mysqladmin -uroot -p'mysql_password ' -i 2 processlist

Will generate processlist and automatically refresh on every minutes

Comment: Would you mind posting a sample output, to see what it looks like? Thanks :-)